# Creating a Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate from a view function

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#

A CollectionView (or ListView) provides a way to view a sequence of objects (of type `T`). It has the advantage, compared to a StackLayout or Grid, that views are only loaded as needed.

The natural way to specify the view for each object would be to provide a function `v:T->View` (F#).

However CollectionView/ListView expects a `DataTemplate`. The [DataTemplate class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datatemplate?view=xamarin-forms) is very tied to bindings and as such the API is unnatural, uninformative and type-unsafe. The useful property seems to be `Values` with type `IDictionary<BindableProperty,Object>`.

Is it possible to work around this API and make a function which takes a `v:T->View` and returns a `DataTemplate`? This would allow making a clean API for DataTemplate and therefore for ListView and CollectionView.

Comment: One approach would be:
1. Create a `type BindContainer<T>(t:T) = member this.Contents = t` where Contents is changed to be a bindable-friendly thing.
2. Instead of passing in a list of `T` as items, pass in a list of `BindContainer<T>`, converting this list into an ObservableCollection (to be bindable-friendly).
3. Define a DataTemplate using a "function" which creates a `ContentView`, sets a binding on it with `.SetBinding(ContentView.ContentProperty,"Contents")`, and returns it. Would be great if someone who has used bindings in code before could flesh this idea out/simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to create your own DataTemplate and ViewCell.

DataTemplate only requires a type deriving from ViewCell to instantiate when needed by the ListView.
It then calls the `OnBindingContextChanged` method of this newly created/reused ViewCell and passes the corresponding value of the element.

At this moment, you have access to the `ViewCell.View` property which will contain the control you want to display.
You can execute your function at that time.

In your case, since you have a list of `'T`, this would be something like this:

```
type FuncViewCell(createFunc: 'T -> View) =
    inherit ViewCell()

    override x.OnBindingContextChanged () =
        let data = x.BindingContext :?> 'T
        x.View <- createFunc data

type FuncDataTemplate(createFunc: 'T -> View) =
    inherit DataTemplate(fun () -> FuncViewCell(createFunc))


(...)

let createViewForData data =
    Button(Text = data.Text)

let listView = ListView()
listView.ItemTemplate <- FuncDataTemplate(createViewForData)
listView.ItemsSource <- dataSource

----

Or even directly:

type FuncListView(createFunc) =
    inherit ListView(DataTemplate = FuncDataTemplate(createFunc))

let listView = FuncListView(createViewForData)
listView.ItemsSource <- dataSource
```

A similar approach can be found in Fabulous.XamarinForms.

The difference is that the element comes with its own view creation function. So there is no need to extend DataTemplate to pass a function.

https://github.com/fsprojects/Fabulous/blob/79c5df748fff7a108dfbcbf8609cb2265a8fddc7/Fabulous.XamarinForms/src/Fabulous.XamarinForms.Core/CustomControls.fs#L110-L151

Answer (score 1):

the solution would be to use DataTemplateSelector.

Here is the link for this:-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

What you can do is get a DataTemplate Id from an API call and based on the Id you can select that particular DataTemplate. You will have make that many DataTemplates and store in the Xaml of the Page. This would be the most safest and easiest solution.

Comment: Also, you can convert any Grid or StackLayout to use DataTemplate by using BindableLayout for Xamarin.Forms..             https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts

Comment: What you seem to be suggesting is that DataTemplates/DataTemplateSelectors can represent arbitrary functions, and in particular are Turing complete. I am skeptical of this, given that DataTemplateSelector is not even recursive. But even if that were true, it would require reverse-engineering the view function `v` and would lead to very complex and non-generalizable code as a result.

(NB Xaml is not related to this question.)